# AWS SES using powershell

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

We have implemented SES in our environment. We are using SES instead of SNS to send few custom email during our batch process.  This is done using poweshell scripts.  Now we want to send attachments with this emails.  Currently our process is done using powershell.  So we would like to implement the attachment facility also in the same.  Saw the example of send raw email which has a inline attachment creation.  Can some one show me a sample of sending email with a existing file as a attachment in powershell?

Comment: how about 3 seconds in google? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/3.0/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage or this http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/send-an-email-with-an-attachment-using-powershell/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a sample:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.Powershell.Admin -erroraction silentlyContinue
$file = "D:\filename.txt"
$smtpServer = "127.0.0.1"
$att = new-object Net.Mail.Attachment($file)
$msg = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage
$smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)
$msg.From = "emailfrom@test.com"
$msg.To.Add("emailto@test.com")
$msg.Subject = "Notification with attachment"
$msg.Body = "Attached is the file"
$msg.Attachments.Add($att)
$smtp.Send($msg)
$att.Dispose()
```

Here is a link for a sample script: 
[Send Email](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Send-HTML-Email-Powershell-6653235c)

Apart from these, PS have a built in cmdlet *Send-MailMessage*:

```
Send-MailMessage -from "testuser1@email.com" `
                       -to "testuser2@email.com" `
                       -subject "Sending the Attachment" `
                       -body "Sending the attachment." `
                       -Attachment "filename.txt" -smtpServer smtp.server.com
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you Ranadip, the smtp option helped.

Comment: @Naga: Happy that it fulfills your requirement.